# Tic Tac Toe Game not checking for winner on android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a Tic Tac Toe inspired game in Android Studio and I am having trouble when it tries to check if there is a winner. I think it has to do with the method I created to check if there is a winner but I am not sure.. Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
String currentplayer = "player1";
TextView tilWins;
TextView ampWins;
Button button1;
Button button2;
Button button3;
Button button4;
Button button5;
Button button6;
Button button7;
Button button8;
Button button9;
Integer tWins;
Integer aWins;


public void checkWinner () {

    String check1 = button1.toString();
    String check2 = button2.toString();
    String check3 = button3.toString();
    String check4 = button4.toString();
    String check5 = button5.toString();
    String check6 = button6.toString();
    String check7 = button7.toString();
    String check8 = button8.toString();
    String check9 = button9.toString();


    if (check1.equals(check2) && check1.equals(check3)) {
        if (check1.equals("~")) {
            tilWins.setText(tWins + 1);
        } else {
            ampWins.setText(aWins + 1);
        }
        button1.setText("");
        button2.setText("");
        button3.setText("");
        button4.setText("");
        button5.setText("");
        button6.setText("");
        button7.setText("");
        button8.setText("");
        button9.setText("");
    }

    else if (check4.equals(check5) && check4.equals(check6)) {
        if (check4.equals("~")) {
            tilWins.setText(tWins + 1);
        } else {
            ampWins.setText(aWins + 1);
        }
        button1.setText("");
        button2.setText("");
        button3.setText("");
        button4.setText("");
        button5.setText("");
        button6.setText("");
        button7.setText("");
        button8.setText("");
        button9.setText("");
    }

    else if (check7.equals(check8) && check7.equals(check9)) {
        if (check7.equals("~")) {
            tilWins.setText(tWins + 1);
        } else {
            ampWins.setText(aWins + 1);
        }
        button1.setText("");
        button2.setText("");
        button3.setText("");
        button4.setText("");
        button5.setText("");
        button6.setText("");
        button7.setText("");
        button8.setText("");
        button9.setText("");
    }

    else if (check1.equals(check4) && check1.equals(check7)) {
        if (check1.equals("~")) {
            tilWins.setText(tWins + 1);
        } else {
            ampWins.setText(aWins + 1);
        }
        button1.setText("");
        button2.setText("");
        button3.setText("");
        button4.setText("");
        button5.setText("");
        button6.setText("");
        button7.setText("");
        button8.setText("");
        button9.setText("");
    }

    else if (check2.equals(check5) && check2.equals(check8)) {
        if (check2.equals("~")) {
            tilWins.setText(tWins + 1);
        } else {
            ampWins.setText(aWins + 1);
        }
        button1.setText("");
        button2.setText("");
        button3.setText("");
        button4.setText("");
        button5.setText("");
        button6.setText("");
        button7.setText("");
        button8.setText("");
        button9.setText("");
    }

    else if (check3.equals(check6) && check3.equals(check9)) {
        if (check3.equals("~")) {
            tilWins.setText(tWins + 1);
        } else {
            ampWins.setText(aWins + 1);
        }
        button1.setText("");
        button2.setText("");
        button3.setText("");
        button4.setText("");
        button5.setText("");
        button6.setText("");
        button7.setText("");
        button8.setText("");
        button9.setText("");
    }

    else if (check1.equals(check5) && check1.equals(check9)) {
        if (check1.equals("~")) {
            tilWins.setText(tWins + 1);
        } else {
            ampWins.setText(aWins + 1);
        }
        button1.setText("");
        button2.setText("");
        button3.setText("");
        button4.setText("");
        button5.setText("");
        button6.setText("");
        button7.setText("");
        button8.setText("");
        button9.setText("");
    }

    else if (check3.equals(check5) && check3.equals(check7)) {
        if (check3.equals("~")) {
            tilWins.setText(tWins + 1);
        } else {
            ampWins.setText(aWins + 1);
        }
        button1.setText("");
        button2.setText("");
        button3.setText("");
        button4.setText("");
        button5.setText("");
        button6.setText("");
        button7.setText("");
        button8.setText("");
        button9.setText("");
    }
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tilWins = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tildeWins);
    ampWins = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ampersandWins);

    String tiWins = tilWins.getText().toString();
    String amWins = ampWins.getText().toString();
    tWins = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(tiWins));
    aWins = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(amWins));

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.box1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (button1.getText() == "") {
                if (currentplayer.equals("player1")) {
                    button1.setText("~");
                } else {
                    button1.setText("&");
                }
                changePlayer(currentplayer);
                checkWinner();

            }

        }

    });

    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.box2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (button2.getText() == "") {
                if (currentplayer.equals("player1")) {
                    button2.setText("~");
                } else {
                    button2.setText("&");
                }
                changePlayer(currentplayer);
                checkWinner();
            }

        }
        });

    button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.box3);
    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (button3.getText() == "") {
                if (currentplayer.equals("player1")) {
                    button3.setText("~");
                } else {
                    button3.setText("&");
                }
                changePlayer(currentplayer);
                checkWinner();
            }

        }
    });

    button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.box4);
    button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (button4.getText() == "") {
                if (currentplayer.equals("player1")) {
                    button4.setText("~");
                } else {
                    button4.setText("&");
                }
                changePlayer(currentplayer);
                checkWinner();
            }

        }
    });

    button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.box5);
    button5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (button5.getText() == "") {
                if (currentplayer.equals("player1")) {
                    button5.setText("~");
                } else {
                    button5.setText("&");
                }
                changePlayer(currentplayer);
                checkWinner();
            }

        }
    });

    button6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.box6);
    button6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (button6.getText() == "") {
                if (currentplayer.equals("player1")) {
                    button6.setText("~");
                } else {
                    button6.setText("&");
                }
                changePlayer(currentplayer);
                checkWinner();
            }

        }
    });

    button7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.box7);
    button7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (button7.getText() == "") {
                if (currentplayer.equals("player1")) {
                    button7.setText("~");
                } else {
                    button7.setText("&");
                }
                changePlayer(currentplayer);
                checkWinner();
            }

        }
    });

    button8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.box8);
    button8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (button8.getText() == "") {
                if (currentplayer.equals("player1")) {
                    button8.setText("~");
                } else {
                    button8.setText("&");
                }
                changePlayer(currentplayer);
                checkWinner();
            }

        }
    });

    button9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.box9);
    button9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (button9.getText() == "") {
                if (currentplayer.equals("player1")) {
                    button9.setText("~");
                } else {
                    button9.setText("&");
                }
                changePlayer(currentplayer);
                checkWinner();
            }

        }
    });
}

public void changePlayer (String player) {

    if (player.equals("player1")) {
        currentplayer = "player2";
    } else {
        currentplayer = "player1";
    }
}
```

Here is the XML file if needed:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/sJJ">

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
    android:useDefaultMargins="false"
    android:transitionGroup="false"
    android:touchscreenBlocksFocus="false"
    android:rowOrderPreserved="false"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Tildes and Ampersands"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="55dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/box1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:maxHeight="100dp"
        android:maxLength="100"
        android:maxWidth="100dp"
        android:minHeight="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:textSize="40dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/box2"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:maxHeight="100dp"
        android:maxLength="100"
        android:maxWidth="100dp"
        android:minHeight="100dp"
        android:textSize="40dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/box3"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:maxHeight="100dp"
        android:maxLength="100"
        android:maxWidth="100dp"
        android:minHeight="100dp"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/box4"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:maxHeight="100dp"
        android:maxLength="100"
        android:maxWidth="100dp"
        android:minHeight="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:textSize="40dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/box5"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:maxHeight="100dp"
        android:maxLength="100"
        android:maxWidth="100dp"
        android:minHeight="100dp"
        android:textSize="40dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/box6"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:maxHeight="100dp"
        android:maxLength="100"
        android:maxWidth="100dp"
        android:minHeight="100dp"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/box7"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:maxHeight="100dp"
        android:maxLength="100"
        android:maxWidth="100dp"
        android:minHeight="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:textSize="40dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/box8"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:maxHeight="100dp"
        android:maxLength="100"
        android:maxWidth="100dp"
        android:minHeight="100dp"
        android:textSize="40dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/box9"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:maxHeight="100dp"
        android:maxLength="100"
        android:maxWidth="100dp"
        android:minHeight="100dp"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="    Wins"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="125dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="            Tildes:"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_row="5"
        android:layout_column="0" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/tildeWins"
        android:layout_row="5"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:text="0" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Ampersands:"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_row="6"
        android:layout_column="0" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/ampersandWins"
        android:layout_row="6"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:text="0" />
</GridLayout>
```

Comment: What's your question?  What isn't working, what are you getting and what did you expect?

Comment: I am trying to check to see if there are three of the same symbols in any given row, column, or diagonal. I was expecting for the board to clear and add one to a count of wins for either side, and nothing is happening. Symbols appear but nothing happens when there should be a winner.

Comment: You should use a 2-dimensional array for your play grid. Checking if there's a winner gets a lot easier then (and a lot more readable). I'm guessing that you made some mistake in your checkWinner() function, but it's hard to tell. Try using a debugger to see what happens in that function step-by-step.

Comment: I would be willing to try the two dimensional array but it is for a school project and do not have time to rewrite my program. It would be ideal if I could simply adjust the existing code.

Answer (score 0):

`if (check1.equals(check2) && check1.equals(check3)) {`

So... If each row is either all player 1... or all player 2... or all EMPTY?

`button1.setText("");`

Then clear the board regardless.

After the first move, there IS going to be a row that is entirely empty (and thus, equal to itself), and the board will be immediately cleared. Also player 2 will win because player 1 doesn't, not on the merits of actually winning, making a 'cats game' impossible.

I'm guessing this is not how you expected the game to operate? You could use more functions... and more arrays... and maybe a pattern or two. ;)